# Access javascript variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'am trying to create a web app with google map direction API,In a             variable`summaryPanel.innerHTML`Contains the details regarding the address and distance.I required to use distance for other calculations ,so how can i access the variable,can we access the variable from the angular controller?

**script.js**

```
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var waypts = [];
    var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
        waypts.push({
          location: checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover: true
        });
      }
    }

    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
              '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
          console.log(summaryPanel.innerHTML);//Variable required to access
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Grab the angular docs for the synatx to add it to the $scope of your angualr controller.

Comment: Yes .. you can access it from angular js if variable is defined as global variable ( out of functions)

But this is not good way to do..

Its good if you will do it using $scope or $rootScope

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var htmlString = $(summaryPanel).html();
```

Then you'll have to parse whatever htmlString comes out to, but it will have what you're looking for.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: It seems a lot like the OP already has the data they're looking for since they created the summaryPanel and populated it.

Comment: Exactly. So there is no reason to fetch it from the DOM and parse it again. The solution woll probably look something like `$scope.distance = route.legs[i].distance.text`, since that's part of what is inserted into the innerHTML you want to parse.